# Join entities using Criteria API with relationship defined on owning side only

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have two entities from two modules.
There is a module `device-core` which contains entity `Device`:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "devices")
public class Device extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable
{
    @NotNull
    @EmbeddedId
    private DeviceIdentity identity;

    // other properties, getters, setters, equals, hashCode, toString omitted
}
```

And then there is module `retail` that depends on `device-core` and contains entity `POS`:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "pos")
public class POS extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "device_vendor", referencedColumnName = "vendor"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "device_model", referencedColumnName = "model"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "device_sn", referencedColumnName = "sn")
    })
    private Device device;

    // other properties, getters, setters, equals, hashCode, toString omitted
}
```

As you can see, there is one-to-one relationship (`POS` `<->` `Device`) defined on `POS` entity which is the owning side.
However, there is no mention of `POS` on `Device` side since `device-core` module doesn't even know `POS` entity exists.

I, unfortunately, can not add `pos` relationship to `Device` using `@OneToOne(mappedBy="device")`, because that would create circular dependency between `device-core` and `retail`, not to mention `device-core` module has to work in environments where `retail` module is not present at all.

I also tried to extend the `Device` entity and create `ExtendedDevice` entity which contains the `@OneToOne()` mapping from `ExtendedDevice` to `POS`, but that didn't work either since Hibernate registers it as another entity and requires to add `dtype` field on `Device` side (which I can not modify) or create a new dummy table for `ExtendedDevice` that would only contain one column (or 3 since device id is composite key) and I would have to copy device IDs into it. It would also add another completely unnecessary and pointless join. This is not an acceptable hack.

**Use case**: I need to list `Device`s, left join `POS` and (optionally) do some where clauses on `POS`.
**The problem**: while this can be done using JQPL, I haven't found a way to do it using Criteria API.
This is a problem, since I need to dynamically add predicates based on request params.
The only solution I managed to come up with is really dirty hack consisting of appending JPQL like this:

```java
String q = "SELECT d.identity, p.id, p.name, b.id, b.name, c.identity, c.name"
        + " FROM Device d"
        + " LEFT JOIN POS p ON d.identity = p.device" // how to do this using Criteria API?
        + " LEFT JOIN p.branch b"
        + " LEFT JOIN b.company c";

List<String> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
if (criteria.getVendor() != null)
    predicates.add("lower(d.identity.vendor) LIKE lower(concat('%', :vendor, '%'))");
if (criteria.getModel() != null)
    predicates.add("lower(d.identity.model) LIKE lower(concat('%', :model, '%'))");
if (criteria.getSerialNumber() != null)
    predicates.add("lower(d.identity.serialNumber) LIKE lower(concat('%', :serialNumber, '%'))");
if (criteria.getPosName() != null)
    predicates.add("lower(p.name) LIKE lower(concat('%', :posName, '%'))");
if (criteria.getBranchName() != null)
    predicates.add("lower(b.name) LIKE lower(concat('%', :branchName, '%'))");
if (criteria.getCompanyName() != null)
    predicates.add("lower(c.name) LIKE lower(concat('%', :companyName, '%'))");

if (predicates.size() > 0) {
    q += " WHERE " + String.join(" AND ", predicates);
}

TypedQuery<Object[]> emQ = em.createQuery(q, Object[].class);

if (criteria.getVendor() != null)
    emQ.setParameter("vendor", criteria.getVendor());
if (criteria.getModel() != null)
    emQ.setParameter("model", criteria.getModel());
if (criteria.getSerialNumber() != null)
    emQ.setParameter("serialNumber", criteria.getSerialNumber());
if (criteria.getPosName() != null)
    emQ.setParameter("posName", criteria.getPosName());
if (criteria.getBranchName() != null)
    emQ.setParameter("branchName", criteria.getBranchName());
if (criteria.getCompanyName() != null)
    emQ.setParameter("companyName", criteria.getCompanyName());
```

I hate it. You hate it. Everyone should hate it. It's awful. It works though.

Now the question is: is there a cleaner way of achieving this rather standard use case?
Or is Criteria API simply not meant to be used in highly modularized projects?
Are there alternatives I should consider?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The reason `LEFT JOIN POS p ON d.identity = p.device` has no Criteria API equivalent is that the `JOIN ON` syntax is specific to Hibernate. The only workaround I can think of is to change the query root and `SELECT ... FROM Pos` instead. Unfortunately, `RIGHT JOIN`s are not supported by Hibernate

Comment: As a side note: 'is Criteria API simply not meant to be used in highly modularized projects?' Well, TBH, the *usual* approach in highly modularized projects would be to avoid reaching across module boundaries in queries in the first place

Comment: @crizzis Thanks for your answer. Yes, I tried to use right join but as you already mentioned, Hibernate doesn't support it. When it comes to avoiding reaching across module boundaries, it can become complicated. Inheritance of modules was an architectural decision made a long time ago and child modules are allowed to reference parent module's APIs and Entities.